# python rest saving parsed xml document - error encoding

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a function that should save the xml from response to file. Input arguments are response and name of file (objNm:)

```
def getXml ( response, objNm):
    root = ET.fromstring(response.text)
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    xmlNm = objNm + ".xml"
    tree.write(open(xmlNm, 'w'), encoding='unicode')
    print('Object {} was succsessfully created.'.format(xmlNm))
```

That returns me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 56, 
    in <module> getXml(response, 'test_example') 
    File "test.py", line 17, in getXml root = ET.fromstring(response.text) 
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML parser.feed(text) 
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1640, in feed self._parser.Parse(data, 0) 
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 142489-142490: ordinal not in range(128)
```

An error with using  root = ET.fromstring(response.text.decode('utf-8'))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    getXml(response, 'test_example')
  File "test.py", line 17, in getXml
    root = ET.fromstring(response.text.decode('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 142489-142490: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried encoding utf 8, did not help either.

Can anybody halp me eliminate this error?

Comment: At what line does this raise?

Comment: Can you copy here by any chance the text between these indexes? `142489-142490` ? Theoretically you could do a slice like `response.text[142489:142490+1]`

Comment: Ã«
that's what it gives after the slice

Comment: And I'm assuming that `type(response.text)` yields `bytes` ?

Comment: it's <type 'unicode'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `python2.7` typically the python files are open by default in `ascii` mode. You need to specify `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file.

Some other things that can be done:

calling `encoded_text = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'replace')` and then using that for the `fromstring(encoded_text)`.

Tested via:

```
import codecs
data = u'abcdÃ«Ã«aaÃ«'
data = data.encode('utf-8', 'replace')
something = codecs.utf_8_decode(data, 'strict', True)
print something
```

An alternative is to set `utf-8` system wide like:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: @JanFi86 check my answer regarding the file encoding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: @JanFi86 really?? ... I was trying the following `codecs.utf_8_decode(u'abcdÃ«', 'strict', True)` in my python console but still got some errors even with specifying the `utf-8` encoding... now I'm baffled.

Comment: @JanFi86 check my answer again

Comment: calling encoded_text = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'replace') helped definitely, doublechecked, looks fine, thank you so much